# Cannot browse silverlight application in Windows Server 2012 ;IIS 8

Tags: silverlight, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I have a silverlight application which works fine in my old windows server 2008. But when i setup the same in Windows server 2012, the application does launch in IE.The applications first page contains Login screen.When i click on the login button it calls a web service to authenticate the user present in the remote database.Doing this i get an error pop-up IE window with "Target invokation exception". What causes this exception? (The server setup recently).Is there any firewall issues related? any new permission issues in WS2012?

Comment: is your application loading in browser..?are you getting exception when you click on Login button.?